# Mongoid run core mongo action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid on a rails project.
I have an API call that fetches client records in JSON format (array of hashes).

```
users = api.get_users # Returns JSON
```

To leverage Mongo's search, sort, and pagination, I'd like to store the records I get through API in the database.

Of course I could run over every record in the JSON and do something like User.create(user), but I would like to just import all records at once and create each record in the database. Perhaps using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're right -- because your data is in JSON format, mongoimport is the tool you want to use. Once you've imported your data, you can set up Mongoid document schemas to match the data you've imported.

Here's a [helpful mongoimport tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/import/) if you want to try it on some sample data.

For the inventory data in this tutorial, you could set up the schema:

```
# JSON data: { "item": "journal", "qty": 25, "size": { "h": 14, "w": 21, "uom": "cm" }, "status": "A" }

class Inventory
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'inventory'

  field :item, type: String
  field :qty, type: Integer
  field :size, type: Hash
  field :status, type: String
end
```

Some things to note here:

- Make sure that you import your data to the default collection name for the model you want to create (i.e. import to the "users" collection for a model called `User`) **OR** indicate on the model which collection the data is stored in (using the `store_in` method)
- When you import data as a Hash, you have some options on how to represent that in Mongoid. I've just used a Hash in this example, but you could also make `size` its own embedded document.